# Set Selected Item in SelectOneMenu by ui:include Primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

I need send a value or item from other component from main page to include SelectOneMenu and setSelectedItem.

Exmple:
InputText=20
send 20 and search into SelectOneMenu the value 20 and Select it.

Page Main:

```
<p:outputPanel id="desplegableUnidadOrganica">
    <ui:include src="/vistas/proa/comun/seleccion/personaladm/seleccionUnidadOrganica.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="idSelect" value="unidadOrganica" />
        <ui:param name="readonly" value="#{listadoPermisosBean.unidadOrganicaSelectorDis}" />
        <ui:param name="update" value="unidadOrganica" />
        <ui:param name="contenedorDeObjetoABuscar" value="#{listadoPermisosBean.consulta}" />
    </ui:include>
</p:outputPanel>
```

and Include .xhtml

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="#{idSelect}" widgetVar="#{idSelect}"
    value="#{unidadOrganicaBean.selectionControl.selectedIndex}"
    var="index" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
    style="width: 100%;" onchange="#{idSelect}Changed(); #{changedCarga}"
    disabled="#{readonly}">

    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{busqueda_unidad_organica}"
        itemValue="-1" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <c:forEach items="#{unidadOrganicaBean.selectionControl.items}"
        var="item" varStatus="loop">

        <f:selectItem
            itemLabel="#{item.unidadOrganica} -- #{item.cunidadOrganica}"
            itemValue="#{loop.index}" />
    </c:forEach>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText
            value="#{unidadOrganicaBean.selectionControl.items[index].unidadOrganica}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText
            value="#{unidadOrganicaBean.selectionControl.items[index].cunidadOrganica}" />
    </p:column>

</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Can you help me? ty for edit my publish, but i need do this ...

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. I suggest working on your English. In the code I see one weirdness: c:forEach+f:selectItem - use f:selectItems instead.